# ror, how to make a regex dynamic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

given this:

```
if (params[:to].to_s =~ (/^r\+.*@site.com$/)) == nil
```

How can I make site.com dynamic to: `#{SITE_CONFIG['mail_host']}`

I tried

```
if (params[:to].to_s =~ (/^r\+.*@#{SITE_CONFIG['mail_host']}$/)) == nil
```

Which did not work.. ideas?

Comment: What is the error? Probably with the match, because `#{}` is ok. Show examples of what you want to match. (the parens around the regex is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ruby you can create the regexp from a string representation using [`Regexp.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001228):

```
if (params[:to].to_s =~ Regexp.new("^r\\+.*@#{Regexp.quote(SITE_CONFIG['mail_host'])}$")) == nil
```

Comment: This will fail because of `\+`, you have to escape twice.

Answer (score 4):

Define "not work", regexes can contain interpolated strings:

```
pry(main)> foo = "wat"
=> "wat"
pry(main)> "ohai wat kthxbai" =~ /#{foo}/
=> 5
pry(main)> foo = "nar"
=> "nar"
pry(main)> "ohai wat kthxbai" =~ /#{foo}/
=> nil
pry(main)> /#{foo}/
=> /nar/
```